# Trouble Understanding JQuery fundamentals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone explain why in the below code, `$(document).ready(function(){ $("#msgid").html(); });` must be called before I can append to the div with my appender function? If I get rid of that part, and press the button, nothing gets appended to the div, this doesn't make sense to me! I thought JQuery's .html() method just returned the HTML contents of the div, so in my below code it would return nothing, and therefore server no purpose.

CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#msgid").html();        //WHY IS THIS CODE BLOCK NECESSARY?
    });

function appender(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#msgid").append("appended with the appender() function<br />");  
    });
}
</script>

This is Hello World by HTML

<div id="msgid">
</div>

<input type="button" id="myButton" value="click me" onclick=appender() />
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to have the $(document).ready() inside your function. But also, one of the main benefits of jQuery is its event handling, which allows you to stop using the onclick, onmouseoiver attributes in html.

Try:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#msgid").click(function() {
//This function will be performed whenever the element with id msgid is clicked
 $("#msgid").append("appended by an anonymous function attached to the click event of this element");  
})
        });
```

OR

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#msgid").click('appender');
        });

    function appender()
    {
        $("#msgid").append("appended with the appender() function<br />");  
    }
```

Both will achieve the same end, but naming a function saves repeating code as always.

Comment: ahhh interesting, so what that does is say "When the document is finished loading, run the appender() function, and keep the appender() function ready for future use" ?? Is that understanding correct?

Comment: @jqueryn00b No it isn't what it does is say when the document is ready, attach the appender function as an event handler to the click event of all elements matching the selector, in this case elements with the id msgid

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $("#msgid").html("");        //This is to clear the html code that is inside #msgid
        });

    function appender(){
        $("#msgid").append("appended with the appender() function<br />");  
        });
    }
    </script>

    This is Hello World by HTML

    <div id="msgid">
    </div>

    <input type="button" id="myButton" value="click me" onclick=appender() />
```

Hope that helps

Comment: just a comment , with jquery we should separate the click events, we should try to avoid inline code

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

You can greatly simplify your code this way.

```
$(function() {
   $('#myButton').click(function() { 
       $("#msgid").append("appended with the appender() function<br />");
       return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: Yes I did that first, I was just trying to name and call the function explicitly. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want , you can do as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#msgid").html('');        //WHY IS THIS CODE BLOCK NECESSARY? to empty the contents of           the div

$("#msgid").click(function() {   
           appender();
        }); // end of click function
 }); // end of document.ready
```

The below functions behaves like a global function and you can call it from anywhere.

```
function appender(){        
    $("#msgid").append("appended with the appender() function<br />");          
}
```